# Django: Filter object and create for million of records

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

[get_or_create()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=10929#L318) is just a convenience function, but if i need to have (Filter+create) million of record in a single go?. `bulk_create` only create objects but not filtering. Can i do it using `with transition` or `rawquery` is the only solution?

`result = Model.objects.filter(field__lookup=value)[0]
if not result:
   result = Model.objects.create(...)
return result`

Comment: How does `get_or_create` differ from `bulk_create` in regards to filtering? Can you please include a more detailed example of what you're trying to do in regards to the filter?

Comment: What's your issue with running `get_or_create` a million times? The time it will take?

Comment: I just not want to get only. I also need to update if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide possible solutions in Django without resorting to going raw, given the info you have provided. I'll update this answer if you can provide more information like the database you are using and what constraints you are working with (e.g. execution time, data integrity/consistency, etc.)

## **Solution 1**

Assuming you're using the latest Django version, you can use `bulk_create`, and pass `ignore_conflicts=True`

```
objects = [
    Model(field_1='Object Value 1'),
    Model(field_1='Object Value 2'),
    Model(field_1='Object Value 3'),
    Model(field_1='Object Value 1'),
]
Model.objects.bulk_create(objects, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

Note the quirks of setting this parameter to true:

> On databases that support it (all but Oracle), setting the ignore_conflicts parameter to True tells the database to ignore failure to insert any rows that fail constraints such as duplicate unique values. Enabling this parameter disables setting the primary key on each model instance (if the database normally supports it).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

## **Solution 2**

Alternatively, you can use django.db.transaction.atomic to do the following:

1. Filter objects already in db
2. Trim your list by removing objects returned from 1
3. `bulk_create` those not added to the database

```
objects_to_add = []
with transaction.atomic():
     trimmed_list = filter_out_those_in_db(objects_to_add)
     Model.objects.bulk_create(trimmed_list)
```

Note that this will lock the database while the block of code inside the transaction is executing.

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

## **Solution 3**

If you want to keep it simple and no other models/tables reference back to this model, you can do the following:

1. Filter for the records
2. Indiscriminately delete ALL of these records
3. Insert your list

This is very similar to solution 2, but you might be able to do steps 1 and 2 in one swoop in the DB, reducing the execution time vs if you were to do the filtering in python.

## **Solution 4**

If you want to update existing records instead of just not adding duplicates, you can use `update_or_create` to update existing records, and create non duplicates.

Concept is similar to `get_or_create` in that you'll still have to do this per object, but the filtering and updating part is done in one swoop as well in the DB instead of in python

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs, creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of (field, value) pairs used to update the object. The values in defaults can be callables.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: @UmairSuraj added solution 3 and 4. If you can provide the constraints you are working with (e.g. it has to be fast, it has to be atomic, it has to work on postgresql etc.), we might be able to home in to a more precise answer

Comment: It has to be fast and atomic and should work on mysql.